# substituting power supplies safe?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power

I have an old casio casitone CT-310
Rating: DC 9V 8.5W
Battery 1.5V x 6
or AC adaptor AD-5

I'm looking around the house for a power supply to use.
I found the following:
Output: 9V DC 200mA
from a hand held mini vacuum cleaner charging base.

so the keyboard must demand about 945mA (8.5W / 9V) but the supply delivers only 200mA correct? What will happen if I try to use it? will it be very quiet? or do nothing? or get damaged?

Answer (score 4):

If you get lucky, the power supply will either shut down because it is overloaded, or deliver a very reduced voltage. Either way, the keyboard won't work properly, or won't work at all.

If you get unlucky, the power supply will overheat, catch fire, and burn your house down. (I'm not joking - at least about the chance of it catching fire).

A "wall wart" rated at 9V and at least 1A (and preferably a bit more current, so you are not running it at 100% of its rated output) should work fine.

Comment: alephzero is right, the power supply for the vacuum cleaner is only rated for 1.8 watts = 9V * 0.2 A. The keyboard wants 8.5 watts. alephzero's recommandation of 9V and 1A gives 9 watts, which should be adequate.